# On button click have to select the cell index in UITABLEVIEW Xamarin IOS (C#)

Tags: ios, xamarin

On Select a table row when the button is clicked in the row. I have cells that contains a button in each row. My problem is when I click on a button in a row the row does not get selected.How do I make the row get selected when I click a button in that row? Uisnd Xamarin IOS

Comment: Can you add the code including the part that doesn't trigger properly?

Comment: Should it do two different things, when clicking a row and a rows button?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add addTarget for your button in cellforrowAtIndexpath method  like this

```
[cell.yourbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonclick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
-(void)buttonclick:(UIButton*)sender
{
// get your button action here..

}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But it would be great if you can provide me with a sample. I have created a custom button in cell folder. how do i access this feature?

Comment: i already given sample . you have to access that button in cellforAtindexpath method and add target to it

Comment: that concept probably won't work at all, the `–buttonClick:` method has no information about which cell is affected.